# oracle SQL select/join with many-to-one and nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble crafting an Oracle SQL query that returns the results I seek.  It's possible that what I'm trying to do isn't possible.

For a given code in table one, if the code exists in table two and ANY of the flags are "1", then the status should be "1" in the query results. Otherwise, the status should be "0". If the code doesn't exist at all in table 2, then the status should be null.

```
tab1
------------
id,code
------------
1,ABC
2,DEF
3,GHI
4,JKL
5,MNO
6,PQR
7,STU

tab2
------------
id,code,flag
------------
1,ABC,0
2,ABC,0
3,DEF,1
4,DEF,1
5,GHI,0
6,GHI,1
7,JKL,1
8,JKL,0
9,MNO,0
10,PQR,1

(query?)

result
------------
id,code,status
------------
1,ABC,0
2,DEF,1
3,GHI,1
4,JKL,1
5,MNO,0
6,PQR,1
7,STU,null
```

So far, the only query I've been able to come up with is this, which doesn't give the right results in the status column...

```
select tab1.*, (select * from (
select flag from tab2 where tab2.code = code order by flag desc)
where rownum <=1) as status from tab1;
```

... status is always "1", which is incorrect.

I'm thinking that instead of using order by and selecting the first result, it might be possible to instead count the number of "1" flags for each code, but I'm not sure if that would work.

Comment: *"If the code doesn't exist at all in table 1, then the status should be null."* - shouldn't that be "If the code doesn't exist at all in table **2**..." ?

Comment: Why do you have ID *and* code in both tables? Isn't the data redundant? Do you need Tab1 at all?

Comment: Where do the 'id's in the result come from? id 2 belongs to ABC in the tables, but suddenly to DEF in the result? Or is it just a row number?

Comment: @ Mark Bannister...  you are correct.  I mis-typed the table name.  I have corrected the text.

Comment: @ Golez Trol...   The tables are populated by two different applications dealing with two constantly changing data sets related by "code".  This is why the data is redundant.  The IDs are essentially row numbers and are not related to the code.  The important thing is that query results have the same rows as table 1, but with an added "status" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first inclination is to use a subselect:

```
select t1.*,
       (select max(t2.flag)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.code = t1.code
       ) as t2flag
from table1 t1;
```

You can also phrase this as a `left join` with an aggregation:

```
select t1.*, t2.flag
       (select max(t2.flag)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.code = t1.code
       ) as t2flag
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.code, max(t2.flag) as flag
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.code
     ) t2
     on t2.code = t1.code;
```

Both these methods are assuming that flag is either 0 or 1, as in your question.

Comment: Thank you.  Your first query with the subselect appears to work.  Initially, I didn't think it was working because it turns out that in the real data, the "code" field sometimes has trailing spaces, which as you'd expect was causing problems with the t2.code = t1.code condition.  Adding trim() to each in the query solved that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a LEFT JOIN:

```
select t1.id, max(t1.code) code, max(t2.flag) status
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.code=t2.code
group by t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 0 and 1 are the only two flags, what about something like:

```
with tab1 as (select 1 id, 'ABC' code from dual union all
              select 2 id, 'DEF' code from dual union all
              select 3 id, 'GHI' code from dual union all
              select 4 id, 'JKL' code from dual union all
              select 5 id, 'MNO' code from dual union all
              select 6 id, 'PQR' code from dual union all
              select 7 id, 'STU' code from dual),
     tab2 as (select 1 id, 'ABC' code, 0 flag from dual union all
              select 2 id, 'ABC' code, 0 flag from dual union all
              select 3 id, 'DEF' code, 1 flag from dual union all
              select 4 id, 'DEF' code, 1 flag from dual union all
              select 5 id, 'GHI' code, 0 flag from dual union all
              select 6 id, 'GHI' code, 1 flag from dual union all
              select 7 id, 'JKL' code, 1 flag from dual union all
              select 8 id, 'JKL' code, 0 flag from dual union all
              select 9 id, 'MNO' code, 0 flag from dual union all
              select 10 id, 'PQR' code, 1 flag from dual)
select t1.id,
       t1.code,
       t2.flag status
from   tab1 t1
       left join (select code,
                         max(flag) flag
                  from   tab2
                  group by code) t2
         on (t1.code = t2.code);

        ID CODE     STATUS
---------- ---- ----------
         5 MNO           0
         6 PQR           1
         2 DEF           1
         1 ABC           0
         3 GHI           1
         4 JKL           1
         7 STU
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to be as simple as this:

```
select tab1.id, tab1.code, max(tab2.flag) status
from tab1
left join tab2 on tab1.code = tab2.code
group by tab1.id, tab1.code
order by tab1.id;
```

A [sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75ab5/2) gives the desired result:

```
| id | code | status |
|----|------|--------|
|  1 |  ABC |      0 |
|  2 |  DEF |      1 |
|  3 |  GHI |      1 |
|  4 |  JKL |      1 |
|  5 |  MNO |      0 |
|  6 |  PQR |      1 |
|  7 |  STU | (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,
  CODE,
  MAX( STATUS)
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID,
    T1.CODE,
    FLAG AS STATUS
  FROM T1
  LEFT JOIN T2
  ON T1.CODE = T2.CODE
  )
GROUP BY ID,
  CODE;
```

Comment: Using the `{}` button with a section of text highlighted will format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

This gives result as you asked:

```
SELECT tab1.id,tab1.code,max(tab2.flag) as Status
FROM tab1 LEFT JOIN tab2
ON tab1.code=tab2.code
GROUP BY tab2.code
ORDER BY tab1.id;
```